# How can I measure the conductivity of a copper rod?

Tags: electricity, superconductivity, electrical-resistance, thermal-conductivity

I would like to perform an experiment to measure the conductivity of a copper rod. What device can I use to perform to experiment? is there such a thing as a conductivity meter? All i found was an apparatus to measure the conductivity of solutions. Please note that I need get as accurate as possible results.

Comment: Well, you could always measure the length and the resistance with a ruler and ohmmeter, and just calculate $\sigma=1/(\rho * l $)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

conductivity is the inverse of resistivity which is resistance times cross-section area divided by length. So measure the resistance using a micro-ohmmeter and measure the length and area using rulers and calipers.

Answer (score 1):

Experimental use: often you don't have micro-ohmmeter (only AM and VM), or conditions does'nt fit. Good way is to use bridge to create current small enough for AM, or potential big enough for VM. Easily possible even remove AM and VM and use traditional galvanometer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carey_Foster_bridge